# Unix "not in" a set

Tags: validation, loops, unix, input

I am trying to do input validation for a script and basically I don't want it to preceed unless the input is one of 6 possible inputs (matching exactly). Basically I want to make it dummy proof so I don't have to train co-workers how to use it too much. Is there a way other than using an infinite loop with a huge stack of nested if statements? Is there a way to do a while x not (1 2 3 4 5 6) or something like that until the answer is one of those?

Comment: probably, but since you've provided no details about what language you're using, we can't help you. "script" is useless information, and unix itself has no "sets".

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: bash has associative arrays, which can be used as sets, and standard UNIX tools such as `comm` can be used for set operations (intersection, subtraction, etc)... but as-written, this question doesn't appear to call for any of those.

Comment: A less ambiguous title -- _if_ my guesses about authorial intent are correct -- might be "Shell scripting: Validating input against a hardcoded set of options". Not doing that edit myself because, well, guesses, and I don't know if they're correct.

Answer (score 1):

To work with any POSIX-compliant shell (assuming that this is actually a shell question -- it's currently tagged only "unix", which isn't so clear, as UNIX has no shortage of non-shell scripting languages):

```
while :; do
  read x
  case $x in
    1|2|3|4|5|6)   break ;;
    *)             echo "Invalid input" >&2 ;;
  esac
done
```